# Changing from Virtual Hard Drive to Blank External Hard Disk

Tags: macos, hard-drive, time-machine, vmware, virtualization

I have a blank hard disk (1 TB) that has more space than the virtual disk I am running OS X El Capitan on (89 GB). My OS is running on VMWare Player version 12, being used on Windows 10 single language. I want to transfer all my files from the virtual disk to the hard drive. 
Could I just drag and drop the files onto the drive, or are there certain files that wouldn't copy? 
I have another External Hard Drive with my current files backed up using Time Machine. (90 GB)
The drive I want to use as my startup disk is 1 TB and is split into two partitions, one for extra files (345 GB),which I use similarly to a USB and another that I want to install the OS on (585 GB). What is the best solution for this? 
Would I have to download OS X El Capitan as an ISO and then use VMWare's installation wizard to install it on the drive? I apologize for all the questions, but it is very important to me.

> N.B. I have OS X El Capitan from a pre-existing VMWare virtual disk I had on my previous PC. I do not have any installation files or any of the kind.

> N.B.2: I am using the Command and Option keys instead of the right control and caps lock button

> N.B.3: If it helps in any way, I am running my PC on an SSD with 8 GB of RAM, with 4 GB dedicated to my virtual machine. I also have Nvidia GeForce 920M running alongside my Intel dual-core i7 2.4GHz

> N.B.4: I have searched Stack Exchange for more answers to my problem, but nothing truly answered the questions I was asking

Comment: See Carbon Copy Cloner and SuperDuper for the normal answer (and questions here) However they are only expected to work on Apple Hardware. OSX will boot off an external disk -

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question does not appear to be about Apple hardware or software within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: Do you have both OS X installations running? Why not let OS X migrate things from the old system to the new. Alternatively, you could use Time Machine to make a backup and then restore that. I'll assume you have good reasons for not doing that and asking about basically migrating a windows VM from one storage idiom to a second storage idiom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you try to install OS X on some Windows laptop. Or migrate a VM to bare-metal. Besides the fact that installation of OS X on non-Apple hardware is not covered by the EULA it will not work out-of-the-box! The drivers included in OS X are made for/adapted to Mac hardware and usually don't work with some arbitrary components in your laptop. It's really hard up to impossible to find drivers for your non-Apple hardware - not to mention that they run reliably in all scenarios afterwards.

Check the various Hackintosh sites if you find a modified OS X installer **and** boot environment to circumvent the limitations. Or better: get a Mac!